# Can someone help point out to me what is wrong with this no brainer WHERE clause?

Tags: sql, postgresql, select, syntax-error

This is very simple but somehow I'm doing something wrong with this query on my database.

I have this query below:

```
SELECT login FROM accounts WHERE login = "loginname";
```

When I execute this query the result I get is this:

```
column "loginname" does not exist
```

This is a no brainer, why is this query not working properly? I have a login column and I know that this user exists because I've found this person with the rails console. Why is the login criteria referring to itself as a column?

Comment: `SELECT login FROM accounts WHERE login = 'loginname';`

Comment: SQL uses single quotes for strings: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-CONSTANTS

Comment: You've already got the answer, but I always tell people, single quotes denote values, double quotes denote labels (aliases)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try with single quotes `''` if you are trying to match a string

```
SELECT login FROM accounts WHERE login = 'loginname';
```

Check the [documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-CONSTANTS)

> There is a second kind of identifier: the delimited identifier or
>   quoted identifier. It is formed by enclosing an arbitrary sequence of
>   characters in double-quotes ("). A delimited identifier is always an
>   identifier, never a key word. **So "select" could be used to refer to a
>   column or table named "select"**, whereas an unquoted select would be
>   taken as a key word and would therefore provoke a parse error when
>   used where a table or column name is expected.

Answer (score 2):

Double quotes (`"`) are used to refer to object names, in a case sensitive way. In this case, `"loginname"` is interpreted as a column name, and the query fails, since there is no such column. In order to refer to a string literal, you should use single quotes (`'`):

```
SELECT login FROM accounts WHERE login = 'loginname';
-- Here ---------------------------------^---------^
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the " " are the problem if you [believe the documentation](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_where.asp). Single quotes are required for string values.

Comment: Thanks @a_horse_with_no_name. I've changed that, English is not my first language and sometimes these things sneak in.

Answer (score 0):

From the [PostgreSQL Documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/sql-syntax-lexical.html):

> There is a second kind of identifier: the delimited identifier or quoted identifier. It is formed by enclosing an arbitrary sequence of characters in double-quotes ("). A delimited identifier is always an identifier, never a key word. So "select" could be used to refer to a column or table named "select", whereas an unquoted select would be taken as a key word and would therefore provoke a parse error when used where a table or column name is expected. The example can be written with quoted identifiers like this:
>
> ```
> UPDATE "my_table" SET "a" = 5;
> ```
>
> Quoted identifiers can contain any character, except the character with code zero. (To include a double quote, write two double quotes.) This allows constructing table or column names that would otherwise not be possible, such as ones containing spaces or ampersands. The length limitation still applies.

So in your query `"loginname"` is the same as having `loginname` without quotes - it's attempting to refer to a column with that name. To make it a literal string, use single-quotes instead.